# Из двоичного кода в символ ASCII в C#

Tags: c#

В программу вводится двоичный код (Например: 10101001010100) нужно его перевести в символы(строку) ASCII

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможно, подойдёт что-то такое

http://ideone.com/14GcZQ

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = "10101001010100";
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(a, "[01]{7}", m => ((char)Convert.ToByte(m.Value, 2)).ToString()));
    }
}
```

Но если важна поизводительность, стоит подумать о другом способе.